# FBConnect stream.publish with iphone unknown response?

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I am using stream.publish to publish some info to a users wall.  This all works fine.

I am not using FBStreamDialog because i do not want the user to be able to edit the message..... So i have set up my own UI.

It all works fine and the stream is published to the users wall, the only issue is that i do not understand the result obtained from the delegate method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
}
```

I need to understand what the result is telling me so that i can handle any errors.  Currently the following is being printed in the console but i do not know what this means:

> result =
>   100000874992250_117813161591916

Any help or advice regarding this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Ok stupid question... i have found in the documentation that the response is:

> "This call returns a post_id string
>   containing the ID of the stream item
>   upon success. If the call fails, it
>   returns an error code instead."

My question now is... how would i handle the response, so that i know there is not an error.

I cant check against all error codes because there are a lot of them!

Thanks

Tom